# How to render iframe when URL is redirecting

Tags: javascript, redirect, iframe

I have iframe which is working fine has some url like following:

```
<iframe src="http://someworkingurl.com"></iframe>
```

Now I want to redirect this URL to some different URL and I am expecting iframe to render new URL contact on iframe.

Following are the redirect rule:

```
http://someworkingurl.com -> http://somedifferenturl.com (302 Found)
http://someworkingurl.com -> http://somedifferenturl.com (307 Temporary redirect)
http://someworkingurl.com -> http://somedifferenturl.com (308 Permanent redirect)
```

In every redirect case iframe not rendering anything. Is this possible that iframe still render with any redirect?

Comment: Is the parent window loaded over https? In that case you might end up in a [Mixed Content-Error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content) (check the console) leaving the iframe blank. -- If the CORS headers and policies are present and correct on the new location and the new location is responding properly there shouldn't be any problem.

Comment: Yes parent is loading over HTTPS @Christopher

Comment: Then the mixed content-rule applies and it won't be loaded. Check the console. :)